# Behave of nested CATransaction?

Tags: ios, caanimation, nsrunloop, catransaction, cfrunloop

The code below will update the `backgroundColor` immediately after the `commit`.

```
[CATransaction begin];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[CATransaction commit];

sleep(5);
```

But with nested explicit `CATransactions`, screen update only when outer most transaction commit.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction begin];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[CATransaction commit];
sleep(5);
[CATransaction commit];
```

So this make it very strange, because we know runloop will create a outer most implicit transaction each loop. Why this `implicit transaction` is not viewed as outer most transaction when a `explicit transaction` commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an implicit transaction always. There can also be an explicit transaction. The implicit transaction does not commit until all your code has finished running. If you have an explicit transaction (`begin` and `commit`), then it commits when the `commit` is encountered.

The purpose of *nested* explicit transactions is only to allow you to provide different parameters (e.g. duration) for different parts of the animation; the actual commit does not happen until the outermost `commit`. Read [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html):

> Only after you commit the changes for the outermost transaction does Core Animation begin the associated animations

Comment: So when take about nested transactions we always refer to the explicit transactions?

Comment: Yes, your second example is about nested explicit transactions, one `begin...commit` pair inside each other. The explicit transaction is not "nested" in the implicit transaction in any interesting way, because it is committed and is thus irrelevant to what the implicit transaction will later do.